# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError when looping through a large table using JPA

Tags: java, jpa, playframework

```
List<Picture> pictures = Picture.findAll(); //Around 2GB of data (uses JPA/play framework)

for (Picture picture : pictures) {
  byte[] b = picture.image.data; //Image raw data is stored in a different table than Picture table
  System.out.println(picture.file_name + " " + b.length);
}
```

The code above, causes an `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` when running, due to pictures being stored in the database rather than a file reference in the DB.

Is there anyway i can "flush" the memory once an object is finished processing ? 
I tried `picture.em().flush()`, and `Iterator.remove(), System.gc()`, none worked.
Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Seems i found the solution. Clear the entity manager after every picture.

```
List<Picture> pictures = Picture.findAll();
for(int i=0;i<pictures.size();i++) {
   Picture picture = Picture.findById(pictures.get(i).id);
   byte[] b = picture.image.data; 
   System.out.println(picture.file_name + " " + b.length);
   //Do extra stuff with image data

   picture.em().clear(); //clear JPA entity manager
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a list of filenames instead of pictures like:

```
List<string> picturefiles = Picture.*findAllFilenames*(); //Around 2GB of data (uses JPA/play framework)

for (String picturefile : picturefiles ) {
  picture  o = new picture(picturefile)
  byte[] b = picture.image.data; //Image raw data is stored in a different table than Picture table
  System.out.println(picture.file_name + " " + b.length);
}
```

Comment: pictures are stored in DB not flat files, otherwise your solution would work.
I tried this anyway, did not work.
`
`for(int i=0;i<pictures.size();i++) {`
`Picture picture = Picture.findById(pictures.get(i).id);`
`byte[] b = picture.image.data; `
`System.out.println(picture.file_name + " " + b.length);`
`}`

Comment: @DavidDalcu I'm not familiar with jpa but when you go through the picturelist then your list is allready load from db to memory, thats why i thought that a referencelist wouldnt need so much memory and you load eachtime the only the one you need.